# How to use req.session data in an other javascript file expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hours of trying I really don't know how to access session data. When a user is logged in the application the id and name is saved in req.session.

```
exports.form = function (req, res) {
    res.render('login', {
        title: 'Login'
    });
};
var User = require('../lib/user');
exports.submit = function (req, res, next) {
    var data = req.body.user;
    User.authenticate(data.name, data.pass, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (user) {
            req.session.uid = user.id;
            req.session.username = user.name;
            res.redirect('/index');
        } else {
            res.error("Sorry! invalid credentials.");
            res.redirect('back');
        }
    });
};
exports.logout = function (req, res) {
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.redirect('/');
    })
};
```

This is the app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var path = require('path');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var register = require('./routes/register');
var messages = require('./lib/messages');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var user = require('./lib/middleware/user');
var requireLogin = require('./lib/middleware/logedIn');
var api = require('./routes/api');

var
    gameport        = process.env.PORT || 4004,

    io              = require('socket.io'),
    express         = require('express'),
    UUID            = require('node-uuid'),

    verbose         = false,
    http            = require('http'),
    app             = express(),
    server          = http.createServer(app);       
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
    app.use(express.session());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(user);
    app.use(messages);
    app.use(app.router);
    //app.use('/index', requireLogin);

    app.get('/index', requireLogin.auth, function (req, res) 
    {
        //app.get('/index');
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    });
    app.get('/register', register.form);
    app.post('/register', register.submit);
    app.get('/login', login.form);
    app.post('/login', login.submit);
    app.get('/logout', login.logout);
    app.get('/api/user/:id', api.user);

server.listen(gameport)

    //Log something so we know that it succeeded.
console.log('\t :: Express :: Listening on port ' + gameport );

    //By default, we forward the / path to index.html automatically.
app.get( '/', function( req, res ){
    console.log('trying to load %s', __dirname + '/index.html');
    res.sendfile( '/index.html' , { root:__dirname });
});


    //This handler will listen for requests on /*, any file from the root of our server.
    //See expressjs documentation for more info on routing.

app.get( '/*' , function( req, res, next ) {

        //This is the current file they have requested
    var file = req.params[0];

        //For debugging, we can track what files are requested.
    if(verbose) console.log('\t :: Express :: file requested : ' + file);

        //Send the requesting client the file.
    res.sendfile( __dirname + '/' + file );

}); //app.get *

    //Create a socket.io instance using our express server
var sio = io.listen(server);

    //Configure the socket.io connection settings.
    //See http://socket.io/
sio.configure(function (){

    sio.set('log level', 0);

    sio.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
      callback(null, true); // error first callback style
    });

});

    //Enter the game server code. The game server handles
    //client connections looking for a game, creating games,
    //leaving games, joining games and ending games when they leave.
game_server = require('./game.server.js');

    //Socket.io will call this function when a client connects,
    //So we can send that client looking for a game to play,
    //as well as give that client a unique ID to use so we can
    //maintain the list if players.
sio.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {

        //Generate a new UUID, looks something like
        //5b2ca132-64bd-4513-99da-90e838ca47d1
        //and store this on their socket/connection
    client.userid = UUID();

        //tell the player they connected, giving them their id
    client.emit('onconnected', { id: client.userid } );

        //now we can find them a game to play with someone.
        //if no game exists with someone waiting, they create one and wait.
    game_server.findGame(client);

        //Useful to know when someone connects
    console.log('\t socket.io:: player ' + client.userid + ' connected');


        //Now we want to handle some of the messages that clients will send.
        //They send messages here, and we send them to the game_server to handle.
    client.on('message', function(m) {

        game_server.onMessage(client, m);

    }); //client.on message

        //When this client disconnects, we want to tell the game server
        //about that as well, so it can remove them from the game they are
        //in, and make sure the other player knows that they left and so on.
    client.on('disconnect', function () {

            //Useful to know when soomeone disconnects
        console.log('\t socket.io:: client disconnected ' + client.userid + ' ' + client.game_id);

            //If the client was in a game, set by game_server.findGame,
            //we can tell the game server to update that game state.
        if(client.game && client.game.id) {

            //player leaving a game should destroy that game
            game_server.endGame(client.game.id, client.userid);

        } //client.game_id

    }); //client.on disconnect

}); //sio.sockets.on connection
```

And i have a game.js script. it isn't in any route or anything but thats the place where i need to get the userid.

this is de middleware for the user

```
var User = require('../user');

module.exports = function(req, res, next)
{
var uid = req.session.uid;
if(!uid) return next();
User.get(uid, function(err, user)
{
    if(err) return next(err);
    req.user = res.locals.user = user;
    next();
});
 };
```

So this is all i have. so i have this game.js script. and in that javascript i need to have access to the session data.

Comment: You'd just access it the same way, within a callback with the request as an argument, as long as you included the session middleware.

Comment: Can you post your middleware setup? As long as the middleware stack is properly configured, all route middleware should have access to the `req.session` object.

Comment: i added the app.js and user.js i hope you can help me out

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with your current setup without a lot of hacking. Each session is reliant on the user's SID found in the request's cookie. Thus, the session is strongly coupled to the request object. You will have to find a clever way to initialize your `game.js` module through middleware. Something like:

```
var Game = require('./game');

// -- Place this AFTER your session middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.game = new Game(req);
    next();
});
```

And then inside of `game.js`

```
var Game = module.exports = function (req) {
    // do stuff with req.session here
    this.req = req;
}

Game.prototype.getSessionID = function () {
    return this.req.session.uid;
}
```

Hope that helps you get there. My honest opinion is that you might want to reconsider your design as your modules that don't work with the request object directly shouldn't be tightly coupled with the request object.

Comment: In the app.js i find the next code      client.userid = UUID();

        //tell the player they connected, giving them their id
    client.emit('onconnected', { id: client.userid } ); So practically what i need to do now is to get the session  in the app.js and give it as client.id

Answer (score 0):

Ok i did a few things to resolve my problem. I really thought to difficult and is really simple.

when the user need to authenticate himself i save the session variables.

```
app.get('/index', requireLogin.auth, function (req, res) 
    {
        username = req.session.username;
        userid = req.session.uid;
        req.session.username = req.param('username');
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    });
```

In the sio.connection there is a function for the game to add the userid and name to the game.

```
sio.sockets.on('connection', function (client, req) {

        //Generate a new UUID, looks something like
        //5b2ca132-64bd-4513-99da-90e838ca47d1
        //and store this on their socket/connection
    client.userid = userid;
    client.username = username;
```

Comment: The only issue I see with this is that you are using variables that are global to the `app.js` file and you'll find yourself in a state maintenance nightmare. Especially if your code base grows and you want to split into multiple files.

Comment: do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Looking at your code above, do you not have access to the session middleware in the sio event listener callback? A la `req.session`?

Comment: I would also read here on how to setup authorization with socket.io, it describes a better setup then what you currently have https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing