# Use Node Express session between different file in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I saved email in session in my **login.js**

```
router.get('/signin',function(req,res,next) {
   res.send(req.session.email);//here i can get email from session as well
   console.log("email inside ./signin in login.js "+req.session.email);
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    req.session.email=req.body.email; //get email from form body
    console.log(req.session.email); // here i can get my email in console 
    res.redirect('/')        //want to redirect to home
});
```

I want to access email from session in my **index.js**

```
var session;
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   session=req.session;
    console.log("your mail is"+session.email);
});
```

And this is **app.js** config

```
var

 express = require('express');
var app = express();
    var path = require('path');
    var connection=require('./models/connection');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var session=require('express-session');
    var index = require('./routes/index');
    var users = require('./routes/users');
    var login=require('./routes/login');
    var debug = require("debug");
    var clc = require('cli-color');
    var router=express.Router();
    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public/images/', 'favicon.gif')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(cookieParser("secretkey"));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
    app.use(session({secret: 'secretkey',saveUninitialized: true,resave: true}));
    app.get('/login',login);
    app.post('/login',login);
    app.get('/signin',login);
    app.get('/',index);
    module.exports = app;
```

[image]

**Want some thing like this we can do in php**

```
<!-- first page -->
<?php
  session_start(); 
  $_SESSION['myvar'] = 'hello';
?>

<!-- second page -->
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['myvar']; // it will print hello
?>
```

I tried these and some more answer but none of them solve my problem

[NodeJS express-session req.session is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138225/nodejs-express-session-req-session-is-undefined)

[req.session is undefined in Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535835/req-session-is-undefined-in-node)

[How to use req.session data in an other javascript file expressjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612275/how-to-use-req-session-data-in-an-other-javascript-file-expressjs)

Comment: Can you post the rest of your app.js file?

Comment: check this @iagowp

Comment: What do you export from `./routes/login.js` ? using both `router.post('/login',...` in login.js and `app.post('/login',login);` in app.js seems a bit strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I tried your code as-is as best I could (copied and pasted from yours, added files that were needed that you didn't post here, e.g. a server.js file that actually starts listening on a port), and it worked as-is with just one change.

Your index.js file does not ever actually send anything back to the client. Note your code:

```
var session;
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   session=req.session;
    console.log("your mail is"+session.email);
});
```

There's no res.send or res.render called, so it's going to just hang.  It has nothing to do with the session value, though, the console.log statement still prints out the correct email value that was posted before.

Try:

```
var session;
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   session=req.session;
    console.log("your mail is"+session.email);
   res.send(session.email);
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot dear @Paul its work fine now :) but i am amaze why console.log not work..while its have no concern i think with res.send

Comment: Not sure, it was working on my machine even w/o correcting the lack of response handling. Glad it worked for you, though.